# User Role Select on Woocommerce Registration Stopped Working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use a drop down menu to select between two user roles on my Woocommerce registration form. After updating to Woocommerce 3.0.8 the drop down menu stopped working and I cannot figure out why. Below is the code I've been using. Any ideas?

```
// Add two new roles.
add_role('dealer', 'Dealer', array( 
'delete_posts' => false,
'delete_published_posts' => false,
'edit_posts' => false,
'edit_published_posts' => false,
'publish_posts' => false,
'read' => true,
'upload_files' => true,
'edit_users' => false
));
add_role('distributor', 'Distributor', array(
'delete_posts' => false,
'delete_published_posts' => false,
'edit_posts' => false,
'edit_published_posts' => false,
'publish_posts' => false,
'read' => true,
'upload_files' => true,
'edit_users' => false
));
add_action('register_form','role_registration_form');
function role_registration_form(){
$wp_roles = new WP_Roles();
$wp_roles->use_db = true;
$role_names = $wp_roles->get_names();

foreach( $role_names as $role_name ) {
    // Ensure that the options exclude default Wordpress roles
    if ( ($role_name !== 'Administrator') and ($role_name !== 'Editor') and ($role_name !== 'Author') and ($role_name !== 'Contributor' ) and ($role_name !== 'Subscriber') and ($role_name !== 'Customer') and ($role_name !== 'Shop Manager')) {
        //  Role value below needs to be in lowercase only
        $role_option .= "<option value='".strtolower($role_name)."'>";
        $role_option .= $role_name;
        $role_option .= "</option>";
    }
}
$html = '
<style type="text/css">
        #role {
        background:#FBFBFB none repeat scroll 0 0;
        border:1px solid #E5E5E5;
        font-size:15px;
                    color:#3a3a3a;
        margin-bottom:16px;
        margin-right:6px;
        margin-top:2px;
        padding:3px;
        width:35%;
    }
</style>

<div width="100%">
    <p>
        <label style="display: block; margin-bottom: 5px;">' . __('Are you a Dealer or Distributor?', 'Role') . '
            <select id="role" name="role" class="input">
            ' . $role_option . '
            </select>
        </label>
    </p>
</div>
';
echo $html;
}
add_action('user_register', 'register_role');
function register_role($user_id, $password="", $meta=array()) {
$userdata = array();
$userdata['ID'] = $user_id;
$userdata['role'] = $_POST['role'];
// allow if a role is selected
if ( $userdata['role'] ){
  wp_update_user($userdata);
}
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'role_selection_field' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'role_selection_field' );
function role_selection_field( $user ) {
$wp_roles = new WP_Roles();
$wp_roles->use_db = true;
$role_names = $wp_roles->get_names();
foreach( $role_names as $role_name ) {
    if ( ($role_name !== 'Administrator') and ($role_name !== 'Editor') and ($role_name !== 'Author') and ($role_name !== 'Contributor' ) and ($role_name !== 'Subscriber') and ($role_name !== 'Customer') and ($role_name !== 'Shop Manager')) {
        if ( !empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
            foreach ( $user->roles as $role ) {         
                if ( strtolower($role_name) == $role ) {
                    $role_option .= "<option value='".strtolower($role_name)."' selected='selected'>";
                    $currentrole = strtolower($role_name);
                } else {
                    $role_option .= "<option value='".strtolower($role_name)."'>";
                }

                $role_option .= $role_name;
                $role_option .= "</option>";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

<?php }

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_role_selection_field' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_role_selection_field' );
function save_role_selection_field( $user_id ) {
//if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { return false; }
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'role', $_POST['role'] );

$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
// Remove role
$current_user_role = get_current_user_role();

$user->remove_role( $current_user_role );
// Add role
$user->add_role( $_POST['role'] );
}
function get_current_user_role () {
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$user_roles = $current_user->roles;
$user_role = array_shift($user_roles);
return $user_role;
};

?>
```

Comment: First things first: where does your registration form template live, exactly?  What directory is it in?

Comment: The form is the default registration form on My Account page.

Comment: Not what URL, what *directory*.  Is it in the WooCommerce plugin folder? Your theme folder? The directory.

Comment: It is the WooCommerce plugin folder.

Comment: The reason it stopped working is likely due to the fact that templates in the woocommerce plugin folder get overwritten when you update woocommerce.  In order to make this change "last" when you update, you need to use the woocommerce template override system: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: I apologize I should have said this from the beginning. I using the default WooCommerce template but my code is the theme's function.php file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I decided to scrap the old code and replaced it with the following code and it works now.

```
/* To add WooCommerce registration form custom fields. */

function WC_extra_registation_fields() {?>
<p class="form-row form-row-first">
    <label for="reg_role"><?php _e( 'Dealer or Distributor', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
    <select class="input-text" name="role" id="reg_role"> 
    <option <?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['role'] ) && $_POST['role'] == 'dealer') esc_attr_e( 'selected' ); ?> value="dealer">Dealer</option> 
    <option <?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['role'] ) && $_POST['role'] == 'distributor') esc_attr_e( 'selected' ); ?> value="distributor">Distributor</option>
    </select> 
</p>

<?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'WC_extra_registation_fields');


/* To validate WooCommerce registration form custom fields.  */
function WC_validate_reg_form_fields($username, $email, $validation_errors) {
if (isset($_POST['role']) && empty($_POST['role']) ) {
    $validation_errors->add('role_error', __('Dealer or Distributor is required!', 'woocommerce'));
}

return $validation_errors;
}

add_action('woocommerce_register_post', 'WC_validate_reg_form_fields', 10, 3);


/* To save WooCommerce registration form custom fields. */
function WC_save_registration_form_fields($customer_id) {

//Role field
if (isset($_POST['role'])) {
    update_user_meta($customer_id, 'role', sanitize_text_field($_POST['role']));
}

}

add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', 'WC_save_registration_form_fields');
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works except for saving user role information, so I made following change in end to save WooCommerce registration form custom fields:

```
function WC_save_registration_form_fields($user_id) {
   
   if (isset($_POST['role'])) {
      wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'role' => $_POST['role'] ) );
     
   }
   
}
   
add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', WC_save_registration_form_fields');
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, this saving line wasn't working in order to change the role so I did something similar and I changed the end :

```
function WC_extra_registation_fields() {?>
<p class="form-row form-row-first">
    <label for="reg_role"><?php _e( 'Dealer or Distributor', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
    <select class="input-text" name="role" id="reg_role"> 
    <option <?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['role'] ) && $_POST['role'] == 'dealer') esc_attr_e( 'selected' ); ?> value="dealer">Dealer</option> 
    <option <?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['role'] ) && $_POST['role'] == 'distributor') esc_attr_e( 'selected' ); ?> value="distributor">Distributor</option>
    </select> 
</p>

<?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'WC_extra_registation_fields');


/* To validate WooCommerce registration form custom fields.  */
function WC_validate_reg_form_fields($username, $email, $validation_errors) {
if (isset($_POST['role']) && empty($_POST['role']) ) {
    $validation_errors->add('role_error', __('Dealer or Distributor is required!', 'woocommerce'));
}

return $validation_errors;
}

add_action('woocommerce_register_post', 'WC_validate_reg_form_fields', 10, 3);


/* To save WooCommerce registration form custom fields. */
function WC_save_registration_form_fields($customer_id) {

//Role field
if (isset($_POST['role'])) {
    $user = get_user_by('id', $customer_id);
    $user->remove_role( 'customer' );
    $user->add_role( $_POST['billing_role'] );
}

}

add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', 'WC_save_registration_form_fields');
```