# Additional user role select field in Woocommerce registration

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, user-roles, user-registration

.

A user role selection is needed in WooCommerce registration form. Users should have a pull down menu to select between "customer" and "reseller" (IDs) wordpress role. Unfortunately my attempt to assemble code fails.

The following code does not assign the selected role and I'm stuck. Registered users still get default role "customer" although "reseller" was selected.

I have changed [the code from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44607961/user-role-select-on-woocommerce-registration-stopped-working) (I dont know whether this code was working anyway)

What I am doing wrong?

The code I am using:

```
/* To add WooCommerce registration form custom fields. */

function WC_extra_registation_fields() {?>
<p class="form-row form-row-first">
    <label for="reg_role"><?php _e( 'Privat or commercial?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
    <select class="input-text" name="role" id="reg_role"> 
    <option <?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['role'] ) && $_POST['role'] == 'customer') esc_attr_e( 'selected' ); ?> value="customer">private</option> 
    <option <?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['role'] ) && $_POST['role'] == 'reseller') esc_attr_e( 'selected' ); ?> value="reseller">commercial</option>
    </select> 
</p>

<?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'WC_extra_registation_fields');


/* To validate WooCommerce registration form custom fields.  */
function WC_validate_reg_form_fields($username, $email, $validation_errors) {
if (isset($_POST['role']) && empty($_POST['role']) ) {
    $validation_errors->add('role_error', __('Role required!', 'woocommerce'));
}

return $validation_errors;
}

add_action('woocommerce_register_post', 'WC_validate_reg_form_fields', 10, 3);


/* To save WooCommerce registration form custom fields. */
function WC_save_registration_form_fields($customer_id) {

//Role field
if (isset($_POST['role'])) {
    update_user_meta($customer_id, 'role', sanitize_text_field($_POST['role']));
}

}

add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', 'WC_save_registration_form_fields');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The user Role **"reseller" needs to be created first** in Wordpress. This can be done with code or [by a plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/), but it's not the purpose of this question/answer.

The user roles are registered in `wp_usermeta` table using the `meta_key` `wp_capabilities` for an array of values, as a user can have many user roles.

In Woocommerce registration, the user get anyway registered with `'customer'` user role. So **you will need to make changes only for `'reseller'` choice**.

At this point, you can do 2 things:

- Case 1 - Change the user role from 'customer' to 'reseller'
- Case 2 - Add to the customer user role, the 'reseller' user role

So your code will be:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'wc_extra_registation_fields' );
function wc_extra_registation_fields() {
    ?>
        <p class="form-row form-row-first">
            <label for="reg_role"><?php _e( 'Privat or commercial?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
            <select class="input-text" name="role" id="reg_role">
            <option <?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['role'] ) && $_POST['role'] == 'customer') esc_attr_e( 'selected' ); ?> value="customer">private</option>
            <option <?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['role'] ) && $_POST['role'] == 'reseller') esc_attr_e( 'selected' ); ?> value="reseller">commercial</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    <?php
}
```

and:

```php
// Validate WooCommerce registration form custom fields.
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_post', 'wc_validate_reg_form_fields', 10, 3 );
function wc_validate_reg_form_fields($username, $email, $validation_errors) {
    if (isset($_POST['role']) && empty($_POST['role']) ) {
        $validation_errors->add('role_error', __('Role required!', 'woocommerce'));
    }
    return $validation_errors;
}
```

Then you will Add this:

For **CASE 1** *(set a unique user role)*:

```
// To save WooCommerce registration form custom fields.
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'wc_save_registration_form_fields' );
function wc_save_registration_form_fields( $customer_id ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['role']) ) {
        if( $_POST['role'] == 'reseller' ){
            $user = new WP_User($customer_id);
            $user->set_role('reseller');
        }
    }
}
```

So in database is correctly registered (as it should be to get readable by Wordpress but only if user role "reseller" exist):

[image]

Or for **CASE 2** *(add a 2nd user role)*:

```
// To save WooCommerce registration form custom fields.
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'wc_save_registration_form_fields' );
function wc_save_registration_form_fields( $customer_id ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['role']) ) {
        if( $_POST['role'] == 'reseller' ){
            $user = new WP_User($customer_id);
            $user->add_role('reseller');
        }
    }
}
```

So in database is correctly registered (as it should be to get readable by Wordpress but only if user role "reseller" exist):

[image]

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).* Tested and works.

---

If I use the following code once user is registered:

```
$user_roles = wp_get_current_user()->roles;
print_r($user_roles);
```

I get this display:

- For CASE 1: `Array ( [0] => reseller )`
- For CASE 2: `Array ( [0] => customer [1] => reseller )`

You will certainly need to use a plugin like [**User Role Editor**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) (if not done yet) to create and define the capabilities of your **"reseller"** user role…

Comment: Thanks for your qualified answer. I tested both cases and they end in "no role" when reseller is choosen. private works. Any Idea?

Comment: to specify: "no role" means -No role for this site-

Comment: @John sorry I have mais an updated… It's tested and works. This time the data is correctly stored in database, for both cases.

Comment: thanks again. Unfortunately both cases result in role "customer" when reseller is choosen now. your last version made the meta_value a:1:{i:0;s:8:"reseller";}
this value could not be interpreted by wordpress, i think. if i set role manual in backend, it is a:1:{s:8:"reseller";b:1;}

Comment: even if i change occurencys of reseller to subscriber (which is surely created and defined in wordpress) new users are in role customer. seems like woocommerce or another plugin forces this role. nevertheless i appreciate your work and let you know if i can reproduce your solution.

Comment: got it! i could use your previous code to store a meta key and made a plugin search for it to then set the right role. thank you so much

Comment: @MarceloCintradeMelo Thanks for this useful update, sometimes I get dust in my eyes :)

Comment: Still working perfectly in 2022