# Forcing Customer To Choose WooCommerce Role Upon Registration

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, registration, user-roles

I have read about this and seen others asking the same thing, but no matter what I do or did, nothing seem to work the way I need it.

I have already removed all other roles (editor, subscriber, contributer, shop manager etc.) and I now only have Administrator and Customer left.

I therefore, need the all new users, when filling out the WooCommerce registration form, to choose between "`Buyer`" and "`Seller`".

**This is the code I am working with:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'user_role_dropdown' );
function user_role_dropdown() {

    $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();
    $wp_roles->use_db = true;
    echo '<select id="role" name="role">';
    
        foreach ( $wp_roles->roles as $key=>$value ) {
        if ( ( $value['name'] !== 'Buyer') && ( $value['name'] !== 'Seller' ) ) {
    
        echo '<option value="' . $key . '">' . $value['name'] . '</option>';
        }
    }
    echo '</select>';
}

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_role_selection_field' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_role_selection_field' );
function save_role_selection_field( $user_id ) {

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'role', $_POST['role'] );
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
    $current_user_role = get_current_user_role();
    $user->remove_role( $current_user_role );
    $user->add_role( $_POST['role'] );
}

function get_current_user_role() {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_role = array_shift( $user_roles );
    return $user_role;
};


add_action( 'user_register', 'register_role' );
function register_role( $user_id, $password="", $meta=array() ) {

    $userdata = array();
    $userdata[ 'ID' ] = $user_id;
    $userdata[ 'role' ] = $_POST[ 'role' ];
    if ( $userdata[ 'role' ] ) {
    wp_update_user( $userdata );
    }
}

add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'new_usersroles_registration_errors', 10, 3 );
function new_usersroles_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {

    if ( empty( $_POST['role'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['role'] ) && trim( $_POST['role'] ) == '' ) {

        $errors->add( 'role_error', __( '<strong>FYI:</strong> You must choose a role for your account. Buyers can not sell. Sellers cannot buy.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    return $errors;
}

add_action( 'user_register', 'new_usersroles_user_register' );
function new_usersroles_user_register( $user_id ) {
$user_id = wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'role' => $_POST[ 'role' ] ) );
}
```

Comment: But do you want to keep "customer" role and add the selected role ("Buyer" or "Seller"). Or do you want to replace  "customer" with the new selected role ("Buyer" or "Seller")?

Comment: I want to remove the role "Customer". Apologies for the confusion. There should in total be three roles. 1: Admin. 2: Buyer. 3. Seller. The Buyer cannot create products, but can buy them. The seller can create proudcts, but cannot buy them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some confusions with the required hooks and some little mistakes. Use the following to display a custom select field to WooCommerce registration form (validate and save data):

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'display_user_role_registration_field' );
function display_user_role_registration_field() {

    $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();
    $wp_roles->use_db = true;

    echo '<select id="role" name="role">
        <option value="">' . __("Select a role") . '</option>';

    foreach ( $wp_roles->roles as $role_key => $role_data ) {
        if ( in_array($role_data['name'], ['Buyer', 'Seller']) ) {
            echo '<option value="' . $role_key . '">' . $role_data['name'] . '</option>';
        }
    }
    echo '</select>';
}

// Validate WooCommerce registration select role fields.
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_post', 'validate_user_role_registration_field', 10, 3 );
function validate_user_role_registration_field($username, $email, $validation_errors) {
    if (isset($_POST['role']) && empty($_POST['role']) ) {
        $message = __('<strong>FYI:</strong> You must choose a role for your account. Buyers can not sell. Sellers cannot buy.', 'woocommerce');
        $validation_errors->add('role_error', $message);
    }
    return $validation_errors;
}

// Save WooCommerce registration select role fields.
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'save_user_role_registration_field' );
function save_user_role_registration_field( $customer_id ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['role']) && ! empty($_POST['role']) ) {
        $user = new WP_User($customer_id);
        $user->set_role($_POST['role']);
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

related: [Additional user role select field in Woocommerce registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053182/additional-user-role-select-field-in-woocommerce-registration/49054519#49054519)

Comment: Do I need to create these roles before they appear or not? On my localhost, the select list is blank.

Comment: Yes you need to create them… you can use this very effective plugin [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/)